# ¿Cómo hacer gráfico de barras por porción usando ggplot para varias variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

tengo esta base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero hacer estos gráficos pero usando las variables anteriores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en donde el eje X de la gráfica sean las variables 1,2,3,4,5 y la porción de la barra sean las variables p26a1 hasta p26a3

He intentado este cogido pero no me da como en la imagen anterior

```
ggplot(data=datos) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=X, y=p26a1), stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas "presentar" los datos de una forma más amigable con `ggplot`. Suponiendo que sean algo así:

```
datos <- data.frame(
                 p26a1 = c(7,5,7,8,7),
                 p26a2 = c(6,5,8,6,9),
                 p26a3 = c(5,6,10,5,9)
)
```

Veamos algunos cambios:

- La variable `x` parece ser el número de fila, va a ser mucho más cómodo que la materialices como columna
- Las variables `p26a*` habrá que llevarlas a filas para poder considerarlas como áreas independientes de cada barra
- Cada valor independiente de `x` hay que llevarlo a una única columna

Algo como esto:

```
new_datos <- data.frame(
                  x = rep(1:nrow(datos), 3),
                  grupo = rep(c("p26a1","p26a2", "p26a3"), each=5), 
                  y = c(datos$p26a1, datos$p26a2, datos$p26a3)
)
new_datos

   x grupo  y
1  1 p26a1  7
2  2 p26a1  5
3  3 p26a1  7
4  4 p26a1  8
5  5 p26a1  7
6  1 p26a2  6
7  2 p26a2  5
8  3 p26a2  8
9  4 p26a2  6
10 5 p26a2  9
11 1 p26a3  5
12 2 p26a3  6
13 3 p26a3 10
14 4 p26a3  5
15 5 p26a3  9
```

Esta estructura de datos es la más transparente para `ggplot`, una única columna para la variable `x`, otra para la variable `y` y eventualmente otra columna única para identificar las areas de cada barra. Ahora sí es más sencillo todo:

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(data=new_datos) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=grupo), stat="identity")
```

La variable `grupo` la usamos para establecer el área que le corresponde en cada barra mediante el parámetro `fill`.

Resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]